# Cut block of text with php and wrap it

Tags: php

So let's say that I have a block of text which can be 1000 lines or more, and I want every 200 lines to cut a block out and wrap it in a div?

I could find a solution, mabe you guys can give me a snippet to start on if you like.

Thanks.

Comment: Are we speaking of lines or words? Lines are not a fixed length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your lines are separated with `\n`:

```
 // Split text into separate lines
 $lines = explode("\n",$text);

 // This will hold the resulting string
 $output = '';

 // Loop the array 200 lines at a time
 for ($pos = 0, $linesLeft = count($lines); $linesLeft > 200; $pos += 200, $linesLeft -= 200) {
   $output .= '<div>'.implode("\n",array_slice($lines,$pos,200))."</div>\n";
 }

 // Add the last block, if any
 if ($linesLeft > 0) {
   $output .= '<div>'.implode("\n",array_slice($lines,$pos))."</div>";
 }
```

**EDIT** If you are dealing with words and not lines, just replace `\n` with a space. Or do:

```
 $lines = preg_split('/\s+/',$text);
```

Comment: OMG thank you sooooo much for your time, the right solution was using `$lines = preg_split('/\s+/',$text);` thank youuu